# Is there a trollish/novelty/esoteric citation style?

Tags: citations, code, citation-style

In programming, there are these so-called "[esoteric  programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language)" like "LOLCODE" or "Shakespeare," which really have pretty much zero usefulness. They are just kind of a novelty, or if a computer science professor is feeling like being particularly obnoxious he can choose it as the language for one of his assignments.

I was wondering if there is anything similar for citation styles. Citation styles are a "language" of sorts, and in principle you could have the analog of "LOLCODE" for making citations. I have never heard of such a thing, and I was considering inventing one---you know, something for a Humanities professor to require if they are feeling like being particularly obnoxious---but I wanted to make sure that such a thing didn't already exist.

Comment: I'd say, any of the traditional styles that includes a requirement for listing the city a publisher is located in.  In our digital and globalized society, how is it even meaningful to talk about "the" location of a major international publishing house?

Comment: That at least _used_ to have a legitimate reason (or so I've heard): that printings of the same book in different cities wouldn't necessarily be the same, so you had to know which city the book came from to make sense of a reference. Of course this hasn't been a valid reason for a _very_ long time.

Comment: @jakebeal see [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/why-is-the-city-of-publication-important-in-most-bibliography-format) on using city of publication in citation

Comment: If you want to troll, you can do this well enough with any given style. Just cite a 600-page textbook without giving any section or page numbers, or cite a published version with a page number coming from the arXiv preprint. Also "and references therein" :)

Answer (score 9):

May I humbly suggest [footnote labyrinths](http://xkcd.com/1208/)?

[image]

Alt text: Every time you read this mouseover, toggle between interpreting nested footnotes as footnotes on footnotes and interpreting them as exponents (minus one, modulo 6, plus 1).

Answer (score 7):

Off the top of my head, an esoteric citation style would be one that uses exclusively doi and/or ISBN numbers instead of author-year or similar styles ---e.g., "as doi:16.1244/0979e.98 says in his reply to 12-9809-090-09..."

Comment: In a similar vein, academic books *should* have (author, year) inline citations. Numeric inline citations are bearable for a 10 page academic paper -- they are incredibly annoying for a 200 page book.

Comment: Don't forget to make them non-clickable and non-copypastable in your pdf file, for addded trolling value.

Comment: @AndyW: Your mileage may vary. I find it a lot more convenient to remember a three or four digit number for the short period of time that I need to open the appendix section than an arbitrary name and a year. The same goes for finding the respective reference in a bibliography spanning many pages at the end of a book.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of `.bst` files (bibtex style files) is obscure enough to be borderline to an esoteric programming language, in my opinion. [Example here](http://kinglab.eeb.lsa.umich.edu///pub/biblios/bst/nature.bst).

<sup><sub>(And don't get me started on TeX error messages...)</sub></sup>

Comment: Your own .bst for pretty documents? It's not for the faint of heart. It's just not.

Comment: Ah BAFLL...happy memories :)